# Calculation of the factorial of a large number in R

Tags: r, factorial

Task: Calculate the factorial of a large number.
In P, the factorial can only be calculated up to 170.

```
> factorial(170)
[1] 7.257416e+306
```

For large numbers, overflow occurs:

```
> factorial(171)
[1] Inf
Warning message:
In factorial(171) : value out of range in 'gammafn'
```

Comment: [This thread](http://www.talkstats.com/threads/how-to-calculate-the-factorial-of-numbers-170.17647/) may be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `factorialZ` from the `gmp` package:

```
> gmp::factorialZ(171)
Big Integer ('bigz') :
[1] 1241018070217667823424840524103103992616605577501693185388951803611996075221691752992751978120487585576464959501670387052809889858690710767331242032218484364310473577889968548278290754541561964852153468318044293239598173696899657235903947616152278558180061176365108428800000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Answer (score 3):

use this and try !you can use lfactorial to use lgamma instead of gamma and get the natural logarithm.

```
lfactorial(1536)
```

Comment: `> lfactorial(171)
[1] 711.7147`

What is it?

Comment: It's the log of the factorial to base _e_. So the factorial is `e ^ 711.7147`.